# How to fix error given in bash console where it says it could not locate a flask application through pythonanywhere?

Tags: runtime-error, pythonanywhere

When I try to use the line `flask db migrate` and `flask db upgrade` in order to update what I wrote in my python code, it is giving me the following error in my bash console.

`Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK
_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory.`

Comment: what directory were you running the code from? do you have an app.py?

Comment: Yes I do! It is working now bur randomly I get that error and never know how to fix it. This is my second time getting that error. My code is based off of the pythonanywhere tutorials

Comment: The trick is to set the `FLASK_APP` environment variable before running the `flask db migrate` or `upgrade` command.  You do that with a command like `export FLASK_APP=myflaskapp.py`, where you replace `myflaskapp.py` with the actual name of the file containing your Flask code.  This needs to be done afresh in each new Bash console you start -- it won't persist between console.  You also need to make sure that you've used `cd` to navigate to the directory containing the file (which will probably be called `mysite` if you're using the PythonAnywhere tutorials).

Comment: Oh that makes sense whenever my bash console would crash I would quit it and start a new one but never realized it does not save. thank you!